How to connect ROS2 Cyclone subnets?
I got the following network configuration:

System A creates a Wifi AP which system B connects to.
System B (PI) creates an internal network and is connected to the two Nvidia Jetsons via cable.
I am now trying to create a ros2 topic on system A and want it to be subscribable by any of the Nvidia Jetsons.
I am using Cyclone DDS and ros2 iron if this is of interest.
What have I done:

Enables IP forwarding on system B's PI

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT


Setup the IP routes on all of the devices
PI:

ip route add 10.21.0.0/24 via 10.42.0.65

Jetson:
ip route add 10.42.0.0/24 via 10.21.0.1

After this setup, I can ping each of the devices from each other and also create TCP and UDP connections (tested with ping and python3 -m http.server + curl).
I then start topics with the following config:
CYCLONEDDS_URI=$PWD/dds.xml ros2 topic pub /foo std_msgs/msg/Int32 '{}'

and try to list and listen to it with
CYCLONEDDS_URI=$PWD/dds.xml ros2 topic list
CYCLONEDDS_URI=$PWD/dds.xml ros2 topic echo /foo

but it does not show and so I am not able to echo the contents.
The two Jetsons can interact with each other and when I start a topic on the system B PI I can see it on both the Jetsons and system A.
I also tried to set the ROS_STATIC_PEERS environment variable. While that worked with the default ros2 dds it does not with cyclone.
I am clueless at the moment. Is there something I am missing?
dds.xml
<CycloneDDS>
    <Domain id="any">
        <General>
            <AllowMulticast>false</AllowMulticast>
        </General>
        <Discovery>
            <Peers>
                <Peer Address="10.21.0.6" />
                <Peer Address="10.21.0.7" />
                <Peer Address="10.42.0.1" />
            </Peers>
        </Discovery>
    </Domain>
</CycloneDDS>


The solution I am using now is a Wireguard VPN. It is not optimal, as it does not allow multicast traffic and therefore peers must be set explicitly.
